# Chart.js canvas : can't center it

Tags: javascript, html, css, chart.js

I'm trying to display a Chart.js graph inside a `<canvas>`, and this canvas is wrapped inside a `<div>`.
I want the graph to be responsive, have a fixed height of 700px and a width of 80% of the page's width. On top of all, I want this graph to be centered inside the page ! My code is below

**HTML**

```
<div class='chartContainer'>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.chartContainer{
    text-align: center;
}

canvas{
    width: 80% !important;
    height: 700px !important;
    margin: 0;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
new Chart(canvasContext, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: hourLabels,
        datasets: dataToRender
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false
});
```

My problem is : I can't center it, the `<div>` takes the whole page but the `<canvas>` seems to have a margin applied to it even though it doesn't appear inside the DOM console...

[Screenshot of the apparent margin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOYun.png)

Can anyone point my problem ? Thank you very much :-)

Comment: Try to give `margin: 0 auto;` to the canvas element.

Comment: Could you create a working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) I could take a look at?

Comment: @Ishaan got it to work, thank you !

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Put this in your CSS

```
canvas{
    margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

Comment: canvas {margin: 0 auto};
or
canvas {margin-top:0; margin-bottom:0; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;}

it's same. @Ishaan and i write the answer before you 1 minute.